# Paginating facebook Graph API using nodejs fbgraph

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api, pagination

I need to paginate the members of a group using node.js and do some data mining. I used node module https://github.com/criso/fbgraph but the pagination was not working as exprected.

Is there any solution that i can use with node.js paginate easily with results from Facebook graph API?

This was the code i used to get admins of the group

```js
var options = {
 pool:     { maxSockets:  Infinity }
 , headers:  { connection:  "keep-alive" }
};
graph.setAccessToken('***');
graph.setOptions(options)
.get("***/members?fields=administrator", function(err, resp) {
 members=[];
 members.push.apply(members,resp.data);
 admins =[];
 console.log("count 1 "+ members.length);
 if(resp.paging && resp.paging.next) {
  graph.setOptions(options)
  .get(resp.paging.next, function(err, resp) {
   console.log("count 2 "+ resp.data.length);
   members.push.apply(members,resp.data);
  });
 }
 console.log("count end "+ members.length);

 members.filter(function(obj) {
  if(obj.administrator === true){
   admins.push(obj);
  }
 });

 res.json(admins);
```

Answer (score 0):

what do you expect from it and what to you achieve? seems you're having problem with async nature of JS functions and calls.

you should probably move members.filter right after members.push

or switch to promises

or switch to async/await